# extract url from string other then href

Tags: php, jquery, regex, preg-match-all, jwplayer7

i am replacing youtube url with youtube video using jwplayer.

```
$str='<a  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6anwsDt8AhA"> sometext</a>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6anwsDt8AhAApr 19, 2015 - Uploaded by Go FreelancerThis feature is not available right now. Please try again later. Published on Apr 19, 2015. How to get anchor ...How to get anchor text/href on click using jQuery? - YouTube Video for get text from html content jquery other than anchor  4:54 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6anwsDt8AhA Apr 19, 2015 - Uploaded by Go Freelancer This feature is not available right now. Please try again later. Published on Apr 19, 2015. How to get anchor ...';


//  $disp_question_desc=$content;
         $disp_question_desc=str_replace("http", " http", $str);
        //get list of youtube urls
        preg_match_all('#\b(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)??(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/)[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $disp_question_desc, $urls);
        if(!empty($urls[0]))
        {

          foreach($urls[0] as $key=> $youtubeurl)
          {
                $div_id=$div_container."_".$key;
                $youtubeurl=str_replace("/","\/",$youtubeurl);
                $youtubeurl=str_replace("?","\?",$youtubeurl);
                $youtube_content= "<div class='youtube-videos-container' srcval='".$youtubeurl."'><div class='youtube-videos  ".$div_id."' id='".$div_id."' ></div></div>";
                $disp_question_desc= preg_replace( "/".$youtubeurl."/", $youtube_content,$disp_question_desc,1);
                $youtubeurl=str_replace("\\","",$youtubeurl);

                  if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $youtubeurl)) {
                    $youtubeurl = "https://" . $youtubeurl;
                    }


          }

echo $disp_question_desc;


        }
```

it is working well when youtube url in normal text. i am facing problem with if youtube url in href tag, there also it is replacing youtube video , i need to replace only urls other then the href tag

output of $urls[0] :

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6anwsDt8AhA
    [1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6anwsDt8AhAApr
    [2] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6anwsDt8AhA
)
```

Comment: You want to replace the url inside the `<a>` or outside the tag?

Comment: outside anchor tag, we need to exclude inside, but now it is working all links

Comment: You need to extract the url outside the `<a>` tag right?

Comment: Can you please var_dump($url[0]) and post it on the question?

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty: update my question

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a whim here and try to correct your first regex.

## Your solution

Change your replacement regex to the one below, which matches only youtube URLs that are not in html tags.

`(?<!\")((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(www.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(watch\?v=|\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9]+))+(?!\")`

If it does not work, post back and I'll examine your code further.

Comment: Disclaimer: Still fairly new to regex, if this is wrong, not working or blew up your computer, please don't shoot me with downvotes

Comment: not working, i have changed like   preg_match_all('#(?<!\")((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(www.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(watch\?v=|\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9]+))+(?!\")#', $disp_question_desc, $urls); getting same results

Comment: As far as I can see, it works: [https://regex101.com/r/pL7iC4/1](https://regex101.com/r/pL7iC4/1) In case you have meant something else, @Naisapurushotham, do let us know.

Comment: I will offer to rewrite your whole code for you but I need very very precise instructions as to how the code should run. What should it do?